# Trying to have Javascript list and find files

Tags: javascript, html, file

Currently (just for myself) I am trying to make an image listing site. I have an upload form already done (using Ajax), which uploads files to an 'uploads' folder. I want JS to put the files into `<img src="">` tags in a UL. (Example @ Bottom).

Here's my current try (Newb at JS).

```
var oldHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var i = 0;
var f = 0;
(function looper() {
    if (f++ < 20) {
        var newHTML = "<span> <img src = './uploads/image' " + i + ".png'>" + "</span>";
        document.getElementById('span').innerHTML = newHTML;
    }
})();
```

Now, I want 1 to be added to the variable `i` every few miliseconds, so it checks for an image file.

Here's what I mean:

- You upload a file.
- It goes to the uploads folder.
- It iss renamed to `image1.png`.
- I want Javascript to put that `image1.png` into an `<img src="">`. That way the image gets displayed.
- Now I want it to add 1 to the 1 in the image name. (`image1.png` would be displayed, along with `image2.png`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].firstChild;
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    img.src = './uploads/image' + i++ + '.png';
    if (i === 20) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}, 50);
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Msnvk/